# AS3 ByteArray " The supplied index is out of bounds" Error

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, arrays

I'm working on an application and I need to save an AS3 object to a db.
Here's what I'm doing:

```
private function getComplete(e:Event) 
{

    var getVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables(unescape(e.target.data));
    var _saveData_obj =  readObjectFromStringBytes( getVars.saveData);

    // do something with the save data.... 

}

public function SaveGame() {    
    var _save_data:Object = _puzzle.dataForSaving;
    var _serialized_string = escape(serializeToString(_save_data));
    var _round_time = Math.round( _elapsed_time);
    var _token =  MD5.hash( _id + 
                            _difficulty + 
                            "mysomewhatsecretstringhere" + 
                            _round_time );

    var request:URLRequest = 
             new URLRequest( _home + 'savegame.php' );
    request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
    var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();   
    variables.saveData = _serialized_string;     
    variables.time = _round_time;
    variables.id = _id;
    variables.dif = _difficulty;
    variables.token = _token;
    request.data = variables;
    var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader (request);
    loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, postComplete);
    loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
    loader.load(request); 

}

public function LoadGame() {

    var request:URLRequest = 
        new URLRequest( _home + 'loadgame.php?id='+_id+"&dif="+_difficulty);
    request.method = URLRequestMethod.GET;

    var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader (request);
    loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, getComplete);
    loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, netError);
    loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;

    loader.load(request); 

}    

public static function serializeToString(value:Object):String{
    if(value==null){
        throw new Error("null isn't a legal serialization candidate");
    }

    var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    bytes.writeObject(value);
    bytes.position = 0;
    trace ("Saved: "+bytes.length);
    var be:String = Base64.encodeByteArray(bytes);

    return be;
}

public static function readObjectFromStringBytes(value:String):Object {
    var result:ByteArray=Base64.decodeToByteArray( value) as ByteArray;
    result.position = 0;
    var the_obj:Object = result.readObject();
    return the_obj
}
```

The problem is that I keep getting a "The supplied index is out of bounds" error when I try to read the object from the Base64 string.... I checked if the saved string and the loaded string are the same. Tried to save the Base64 string to a shared object and retrieve it - that works fine ... the only problem is when I save and load to/from the server.

Can you guys help me? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: does it look correct if you trace `getVars.saveData`?

Comment: Can you call readByte()?

Comment: @shanethehat  Yes I get the same string from the db... that's why I don't understand why I get the error

Comment: @cwallenpoole What do you mean? I'm kind of new to action script

Comment: @lansen Was it the same string or does it just look like the same string? What happens when you have ActionScript compare them: `getVars.saveData == escape(serializeToString(_puzzle.dataForSaving))`. Also what happens when you call: `result.readByte();`

Comment: @cwallenpoole Tried testing with getVars.saveData == escape(serializeToString(_puzzle.dataForSaving))...it seems it's not the same string .... looking into the server side code. I was tracing the string and it looked the same ....  can it be some encoding issue ? I'm getting the string in php via $_POST and saving it to mysql ...then just echoing it from the mysql result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so it looks like we've come to a series of steps you can take to debug what's going on.

1. (In save game) make sure that `unescape( variables ).saveData == _puzzle.dataForSaving`. If this does not work, then your issue is with either `escape` or `unescape`. I have to admit

   - I am suspicious here, you should never need to escape data for a `POST` once it has been Base64 encoded (as3crypto's Base 64 encoding will return only one of these characters: `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=`. Those are all legit in a POST) and your URLLoader should take care of making it a legit request, so I have difficulty seeing the need.
   - It is more consistent (and more expected) to have `escape` and `unescape` both accept strings as parameters and return strings.
2. Instead of storing to the database and then retrieving, store to `$_SESSION` (or, if possible, just echo the value back). This will eliminate PHP as a possible culprit.
3. In PHP, make sure that `$_POST['saveData'] == /* whatever you echo */`. If it isn't, then you have a DB encoding issue. You need to make sure that whatever encoding is used in MySQL is the same as the one used in AS.

As an aside, when working with AS, you'll often find it easier to use `$_REQUEST` instead of `$_POST` or `$_GET`. Since the requests are more or less abstracted, the URLRequests of AS don't really need to worry about being RESTful, and it is a heck of a lot easier to work with than exclusively using `POST`s.

Comment: Solved it ... it was an encoding issue. I wasn't encoding the string properly on the server side. Thanks for "opening my eyes".

Answer (score 1):

try using [`ba.writeMultiByte(string, 'utf-8')`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/ByteArray.html#writeMultiByte%28%29) and [`ba.readMultiByte(ba.bytesAvailable, 'utf-8')`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/ByteArray.html#readMultiByte%28%29) without converting to object

Comment: So... where do I use them ?....  I have an object that I need to serialize and save to a database. Right now I use ba.writeObject and Base64 encode to turn it to string and Base64 decode and ba.readObject to get the object back.